# How to setup different clusters in common IP

Tags: wildfly-8

I have many wildfly-8.2 nodes that has IP address 10.4.0.X. I need to group them in 2 different clusters. Unfortunately I received message from nodes that doesn't included in a cluster. Each cluster receives messages from all nodes since they are all under 10.4.0. Here is my mod_cluster configuration in Apache:

```
# MOD_CLUSTER_ADDS
<IfModule manager_module>
Listen 10.4.0.1:10001
ManagerBalancerName testbalancer

<VirtualHost 10.4.0.1:10001>
<Location />
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 10.4.0.
</Location>

KeepAliveTimeout 300
MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
#ServerAdvertise on http://10.4.0.1:10001
AdvertiseFrequency 5
#AdvertiseSecurityKey secret
#AdvertiseGroup 224.0.1.105:23364
EnableMCPMReceive


<Location /mod_cluster_manager>
   SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 10.4.0
</Location>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be a good scenario to use widlfly in domain mode, that way you can configure multiple server groups (subclusters) and manage them centrally using a domain controller. A detailed tutorial is available here:
http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/07/19/scalable-ha-clustering-with-jboss-as-7-eap-6/

The tutorial splits multiple server groups into multiple load balancer groups on mod_cluster.

To just configure individual nodes into different load balancer groups for mod_cluster (have not tried this myself!), you can use the lbgroup parameter in the mod-cluster-config:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.1">  
        <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" 
        balancer="myBalancer" load-balancing-group="myLBGroup" 
        connector="ajp">  
            <dynamic-load-provider>  
                <load-metric type="busyness"/>  
            </dynamic-load-provider>  
        </mod-cluster-config>  
    </subsystem>
```

ref: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/203907

To actually separate the wildfly instances into separate clusters is another story. There used to be a property "jboss.partition.name" but this has been replaced by defining unique multicast address/port combinations for your cluster partitions within the subnet.

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/177877

So assuming you are using udp as your jgroups stack, you can change the multicast address using the "-u" command line parameter:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Command+line+parameters#Commandlineparameters-defaultmulticastaddress

An alternative for configuring mod_cluster might be to disable advertising (nodes and mod_cluster) and use a static config in your standalone.xml:

```
<mod-cluster-config proxy-list="10.0.1.2:6667"/>
```

That way, the nodes will no longer advertise and the assignments to the different mod_cluster apache proxies would be static.

ref: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/218813

ref: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Configure_the_mod_cluster_Subsystem_to_Use_TCP.html

Comment: I have did all these steps; created lbgroups and used different multi cast address to each group. In my case, there are 2 lbgroups, 2 Apache servers in the front for each group. I used multicast address :230.0.0.4 for one group and :230.0.0.14 for other group. Since each Apache is under 10.4.0.x, they are getting messages from nodes in other lbgroup also. I tried different ManagerBalancerName for each Apache as set in different lbgroups but nothing changed.

Comment: You might try configuring the proxy-list statically for each cluster, I update the answer above.  The proxy-list can also take mutliple servers, in the form: address1:port1,address2:port2

Comment: ok, 10.0.1.2:6667 - is this the address and port of Apache? If so, where is this port 6667  defined? I am using WildFly-8.2 and this will be default port of wildfly? In my configuration it will be 10.4.0.1:10001?

Comment: I think it is actually 6666: https://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html_single/  httpd will run on port 8000 and will accept MCMP messages on localhost:6666 and offer /mod_cluster_manager on the same host and port.

Comment: Update: I checked and found it is listenign on 10001, so pointed to that port.