# How to isolate server groups into particular clusters in Wildfly 9

Tags: tcp, cluster-computing, wildfly, jgroups

How could be done cluster isolation in Wildfly 9?

We are developing a system consisting of a number of packages. Each of them is operated within a different server group, however they together form the same cluster (we are using TCP stack with TCPPING discovery - the only possible way for us now).

This configuration has however serious problems, long delays, timeouts, strange errors. It seems that it helps us when the individual server groups are isolated (e.g. when we switch off the other server groups). This also makes sense - using TCP, every packet needs to be sent several times - for each virtual server in cluster separately.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to efficiently separate the particular server groups. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a similar situation as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31675486/815218

This tutorial http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/07/19/scalable-ha-clustering-with-jboss-as-7-eap-6/

does a good job explaining how to separate your server groups and then put them into different lbgroups in mod_cluster.

Comment: Thank you @sprockets. I have seen both of them before. The only problem is that both these sources are about UDP transport using MPING for discovery, but we are using TCP with TCPPING. We probably need to do something similar, unfortunately unlike MPING that could be just modified by the change of UDP port in socket bindings, TCPPING is configured in stack, which is a part of profile. And it means we will probably need multiple profiles because of it. But this is just my assumption, I haven't seen any relevant document.

Comment: @TomS, did you ever get this figured out? I have the exact some concern/problem. The wildfly example configs for EC2 (in the docs directory) even show multicast setups, which is obviously incorrect.